# Interacting with Sql Server jobs programmatically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, smo

I would like to be able to interact with a Sql Server job programmatically through a web page.

What is the best way to do this? Through SMO? The job will take a long time to run, so it needs to fire and forget, and I would also like to be able to stop it.

If SMO, can anybody point me to an easy tutorial? Google gave me some fairly basic stuff but nothing substantial...

SQL Server 2008, ASP.NET MVC web app.

Comment: Is this for an application to do this or for an administrator who is performing admin tasks? If an app, then I think SMO is the way to go. If an admin, then consider PowerShell (which may still use SMO). But if you answer this, then you'll give us a better direction to move in for the answers.

Comment: Do you want to see progress of the tasks as well?

Comment: This for an application. There is a task that takes about 2 hours to complete. Kicking off the task will be done by a non-admin. Progress of the tasks isn't necessary since it does a lot of db reads/writes and you can measure it through that.

Answer (score 0):

If PowerShell is an option, take a look at [these scripts](http://www.idera.com/Products/Free-Tools/PowerShell-scripts/).

If you want to do it via .NET code, take a [look at this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/7a2c8ed9-6146-42ce-84eb-adf8990dfcbe) - a very basic example for you to start and stop jobs by name.